# extract information from csv file

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have information from a csv file that was originally a json object (list of dictionaries). The information in the csv is saved in rows and it has the following structure:

```
{   'geometry': {   'location': {   'lat': 48.121096, 'lng': 14.868725}},
    'icon': 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png',
    'id': '322572963ad2ccd534d8a6ec3e71eba67953400c',
    'name': u"McDonald's \xd6sterreich",
    'price_level': 1,
    'reference': 'CoQBeAAAAOQrvtFrvdPFavW8IPAtNz5BqUOxB6j0dAWXZzgx673-pYV-JLzDk4q9Q1lK2e1Tmn7xiGSwrOAT27rlnr00NJvskvS7isZOIz48RWv8SZo4jbl_RiiEfpz7SpD3fQNB31aJexfB6n2SsNz6FL8StgZIdErv6u4mR-a-xCbMU5CREhBB3r-DyRrOks1EPQz22JQXGhSmPRi0Ht5k0VPTAFVefDF0HQ3xZQ',
    'types': ['restaurant', 'food', 'establishment'],
    'vicinity': u'Waidhofner Stra\xdfe 1, im City Center Amstetten'}
```

Sometimes the rows contain two or more of these list of dictionaries. The information that I am interested in extracting is the 'lat' and 'lng'. Ideally I would like to have this two coordinates in a data frame like this:

```
lat      lng
48.098   5.0886
48.110   5.1390
48.234   5.1679
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import re
import csv

datafile = open('c:/users/J/Desktop/listaraw.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
data = []
for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)

point_re = re.compile('.*lat.*;')
point_lat = point_re.search(str(data)).group(1)
```

But I got the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: no such group
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this task?

Here is the file for further reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6t5dgbzyu1apef2/listaraw.csv

Thanks

Comment: Your data is *not* CSV. You have simply JSON-like objects (because it’s invalid JSON) quoted in `"` on each line. There is nothing CSV-like about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the double quotes are needed to be replaced with something that will evaluate to Python syntax.

This code will retreive your coordinates:

```
import ast

for line in open('listaraw.csv'):
    line = ast.literal_eval(line.replace('""', '\\"'))
    if isinstance(line, tuple):
        items = map(ast.literal_eval, list(line))
    else:
        items = ast.literal_eval(line)
    if isinstance(items, dict):
        items = [items]
    for item in items:
        print item['geometry']['location']
```

Comment: Thanks, this prints the lat and lng that I need. If I want to print back to a csv?

Comment: @asado23 You'll simply open a new file for writing and write the coords with a suitable delimiter line by line. But wasn't it what got you into trouble in the first place? Use proper json and you will not need ad hoc parsing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

How about loading the data with the json module

Unfortunately, your data are not valid json. Property names must have double quotes.

Here is a modified example

```
import json

data = """{
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 48.121096, 
            "lng": 14.868725
        }
    },
    "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    "id": "322572963ad2ccd534d8a6ec3e71eba67953400c",
    "name": "McDonald's Osterreich",
    "price_level": 1,
    "reference": "CoQBeAAAAOQrvtFrvdPFavW8IPAtNz5BqUOxB6j0dAWXZzgx673-pYV-JLzDk4q9Q1lK2e1Tmn7xiGSwrOAT27rlnr00NJvskvS7isZOIz48RWv8SZo4jbl_RiiEfpz7SpD3fQNB31aJexfB6n2SsNz6FL8StgZIdErv6u4mR-a-xCbMU5CREhBB3r-DyRrOks1EPQz22JQXGhSmPRi0Ht5k0VPTAFVefDF0HQ3xZQ",
    "types": ["restaurant", "food", "establishment"],
    "vicinity": "Waidhofner Strasse 1, im City Center Amstetten"
}
"""

jdata = json.loads(data)

print jdata['geometry']['location']
```